# Docker- Persistent host name

Tags: docker, backblaze

I'm trying to run the container **tom300z/backblaze-personal-wine** to backup my unraid server. By default, the container uses a hash for the hostname, causing each new configuration to be recognized as a different computer by backblaze and causes a new 'computer' to show up on my account. thanks to backblaze's billing model, I have to pay 7$ a month per computer. I tried to set the `--hostname` flag manually but docker appends the date to the host name causing the same problem. Is there a way around this?